# Can you mount new partition to /var/log without rebooting

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have made a new partition that I have for the /var/logs.  I have edited the fstab.  Is it possible to mount this over the /var/log without rebooting the server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some tested steps :

**Step 1**

We check what processes/deamons are using `/var/log/` and stop them , so we can use :

```
lsof +D /var/log | awk '!/COMMAND/{print $1 | "sort -u"}'
```

In my case returns

```
apache2
monit
rsyslogd
```

So I just stopped those services until `lsof`'s output was blank

**Step 2**

Then we need to have the same directory structure with respective permissions, so we can use `rsync`:

```
 mkdir /var/oldlog
 rsync -a --include '*/' --exclude '*'  /var/log/ /var/oldlog/
```

**Step 3**

Mount your new partition and copy the directory structure onto the new partition

```
mount /dev/sdX  /var/log/
rsync -a --include '*/' --exclude '*'  /var/oldlog/ /var/log/
```

Now start the services that you have stopped and `tail` the logs, if everything seems to be fine then do not forget to make en entry in `/etc/fstab`

Note : These steps should be fast enough so that it should not drop logs, so you can write a script based on above steps and check it and run.